# Check url parameter using javascript

Tags: javascript, url

If two url are like:

http://localhost:1113/Project/TestCourse.aspx?id=

http://localhost:1112/Project/TestCourse.aspx

How to check whether 'id' is present or not using javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the URL parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
/\?id\=|&id\=/i.test(location.href)
```

Answer (score 8):

I would tweak @KooiInc's answer to `location.href.match(/(\?|&)id($|&|=)/)`. It catches parameters without values (for example http://localhost:1112/Project/TestCourse.aspx?id) and also ensures you only have id not just a param starting with id (e.g idparam).

Answer (score 1):

use `location.href.match(/\?id\=/i) && location.href.match(/&id\=/i)`

Comment: Would be null in the case of the 2 given urls. Change && to ||