# Send data to next page to trigger an event in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a link on my menu that send a user to a page where, if he used that specific link, triggers an action (it adds a class to a div element).

Right now I'm doing it with php with a link like : `/mypage.php?action=go`
and on mypage.php I check with php with : `if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == go)` and then the php code is executed

However I would like to do this in a JS equivalent, so instead of php I'd be able to trigger a JQuery action. I'm not very experienced with JS/JQuery, how can I do that properly ?

the script JS script that would be trigger is something along

```
$("#div1").toggleClass("class-triggered");
```

Comment: is your question complete?

Comment: how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438326/check-url-parameter-using-javascript

Comment: @chchrist I will look into this, I missed it because how poorly I was trying to phrase my request, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `sessionStorage` to have something stateful in client-side :

- The first page : `sessionStorage.setItem('prop1','value1');`.
- The second page includes:

  ```
  var getParamValue=function(param) {
         var v = window.location.search.match(new RegExp('(?:[\?\&]'+param+'=)([^&]+)'));
         return v ? v[1] : null;
     }
  if(sessionStorage.getItem('prop1')==='value1' && getParamValue('action')==='go'){
        //
        $("#div1").toggleClass("class-triggered");

   }
  ```

Dont forget to run this code after loading the whole page , specially : `#div1`.

```
$(()=>{
    //your code here after load page 
    // Thus, code above should be copy/past here
});
```

Comment: if he visits the page without the url params the above will still be true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! How would this work ? is it just sent to the next page or is it conserved client-side for the whole session ? edit : chchrist is right ! this is very likely to happen since the link in question is in the website's menu (in every page)

Comment: You could drop the `sessionStorage` bit.  Parsing the query parameters for `action=go` will do the trick, and it satisfies the desire to keep it in the JS.  You wouldn't have to add anything in the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you're doing it is the best.  If you do anything with cookies or client-side storage, the user has to have that enabled in their settings, and you have to remember to delete the cookie or storage item afterwards.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is that it looks very complicated and messy to trigger a JQuery script with the php $_GET['action']

Comment: I wouldn't worry about how it looks.  Focus on how it works, and keep it simple.  Query parameters are transient by nature, and I think that's exactly what you want here.